# Magento 1.7 - Product missing in catalogsearch_fulltext

Tags: magento, search, indexing

In my shop i have the problem that some articles won't get indexed in `catalogsearch_fulltext`.

I have imported all products programatically like

```
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$prod->setStuff();
$prod->save();
```

There are some custom attributes configured as searchable, but all of them are filled with data. Also attributes like visibility, tax_class, website_ids and all the required core attributes are filled.
But the product doesn't get indexed into the search table. If i save the product manually in backend without changing any attributes, it get's indexed.

Can someone give me a hint which attributes have to be filled with data to get indexed?
I suppose all "searchable" fields, but this makes no difference in behaviour.

Comment: What is index mode? System -> Index Management. "Update on save" or "manual update"?

Comment: Its manual Update, but i use AsyncIndex extension. But this doesn't work, even if i reindex complete catalogsearch_fulltext.